# How can I use powershell to intercept the windows shutdown signal?

Tags: powershell

How can I use powershell to intercept the windows shutdown signal and perform a write operation before windows shuts down?

Comment: I guess you're looking for some signal handler through PowerShell ? (Not a polling script)

Answer (score 0):

use the following code, replace the $env variable with whatever you want to call. If you wanted to write after it is detected then use a .bat file that performs a write option

```
 If ( [ System.Environment ]:: HasShutdownStarted ) {
      & "$env:C:\scripts\whatever.bat" ;
    }
```

whatever.bat

```
@echo off
echo This is a test> test.txt
```